# html image not displaying properly, puts tag text instead

Tags: html, image

I have a few images between my text and one of them is not displaying properly, can't figure out why...(it's the #abbey one, 4th ul list, 3rd image). This is HTML that is then loaded onto another page using jquery.

```
    <br/>
<h1>Programski jeziki</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><span class="bold">Java: </span>Opravljen izpit Osnove Programiranja kot del poklicnega tečaja Tehnik Računalništva, učenje na lastno pest.</li>
    </ul>
<h1>Spletno oblikovanje</h1>
    <ul>    
        <li><span class="bold">HTML, CSS: </span>Opravljen izpit Načrtovanje in razvoj spletnih aplikacij kot del poklicnega tečaja Tehnik Računalništva, opravljen tečaj na spletni strani <a href=www.codeacademy.com>codeacademy</a>.</li>               
        <li><span class="bold">PHP: </span>opravljen tečaj na spletni strani <a href=www.codeacademy.com>codeacademy</a>, ki zajema variables, arrays, functions, classes, loops.</li>
        <li><span class="bold">Javascript: </span>opravljen tečaj na spletni strani <a href=www.codeacademy.com>codeacademy</a>, učenje na lastno pest
        <li><span class="bold">Jquery: </span>osnovno poznavanje uporabe ter načina dela, učenje ob uporabi ter na spletni strani <a href=www.codeacademy.com>codeacademy</a>.  
    </ul>
<h1>Ostala računalniška znanja</h1>
    <ul>               
        <li>programi MS Office (Word, Excel, PowerPoint)</li>
        <li>poizvedbe po podatkovni bazi (mySQL)</li>                                       
    </ul>
<h1>Drugo</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><span class="bold">Retorika, moderatorika in argumentacija</span><br/>Član mednarodne debatne ekipe 4 leta v gimnaziji.</li>
        <img class="thumbnail" id="cicero" src="images/cicero_thumbnail.jpg" alt="p" />
        <img class="thumbnail" id ="pokal" src="images/pokal_thumbnail.jpg" alt="p" />    
        img class="thumbnail" id="idea" src="images/idea_thumbnail.jpg" alt="p" />                                
        <li><span class="bold">Komunikacija s strankami</span><br/>študentsko delo: anketiranje(klicni center+v živo)</li>                                
        <li><span class="bold">Tuji jeziki:</span>
        angleščina: dodatno učenje angleškega jezika od začetka osnovne šole, obiskovanje poletnih taborov (Bohinj, Anglija)        
        <img class="thumbnail" id ="abbey" src="images/abbey_thumbnail.jpg" alt="p" />
        <a>francoščina: učenje francoščine kot drugi tuji jezik v gimnaziji (4 leta)</a>
        </li>                 
        <li><span class="bold">Vozniški izpit B kategorije</span></li>
    </ul>

<script>
    $(".thumbnail").hover( function() {
      $(this).fadeTo(500, 1);
      },
      function() {
      $(this).fadeTo(1000, 0.5);
    });
    $("#cicero").on("click",function(){
         window.open('images/cicero.jpg','_blank');
     });
     $("#pokal").on("click",function(){
         window.open('images/pokal.jpg','_blank');
     });
     $("#idea").on("click",function(){
         window.open('images/idea.jpg','_blank');
     });
     $("#abbey").on("click",function(){
         window.open('images/abbey.jpg','_blank');
     });
</script>
```

Comment: are you sure the url is valid, and the image is actually there?

Comment: Your third `img` (id = idea) has a missing opening tag: `<`. `img class="thumbnail" id="idea" src="images/idea_thumbnail.jpg" alt="p" />`

Comment: this was the problem, don't know how I missed it

Comment: This question should be closed as the issue was caused by just a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You third `img` tag is missing the opening `<` character.

Change your 4th UL like this:

```
 <ul>
    <li><span class="bold">Retorika, moderatorika in argumentacija</span><br/>Član mednarodne debatne ekipe 4 leta v gimnaziji.</li>
    <img class="thumbnail" id="cicero" src="images/cicero_thumbnail.jpg" alt="p" />
    <img class="thumbnail" id ="pokal" src="images/pokal_thumbnail.jpg" alt="p" />    
    <img class="thumbnail" id="idea" src="images/idea_thumbnail.jpg" alt="p" />                                
    <li><span class="bold">Komunikacija s strankami</span><br/>študentsko delo: anketiranje(klicni center+v živo)</li>                                
    <li><span class="bold">Tuji jeziki:</span>
    angleščina: dodatno učenje angleškega jezika od začetka osnovne šole, obiskovanje poletnih taborov (Bohinj, Anglija)        
    <img class="thumbnail" id ="abbey" src="images/abbey_thumbnail.jpg" alt="p" />
    <a>francoščina: učenje francoščine kot drugi tuji jezik v gimnaziji (4 leta)</a>
    </li>                 
    <li><span class="bold">Vozniški izpit B kategorije</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Take a look at carefully again :)

Comment: Unless I'm blind I can't see the difference here. And to make it a proper answer you should point out exactly what needs to be changed. You can't just leave it for us to figure out.

Comment: it's exactly the same, character for character.

Comment: No this is not the same, 3rd image tag is not valid.

Comment: What's invalid? Can't you explain it?

Comment: *sigh* I spotted it now. If you point out what was wrong, i'll upvote.

Comment: Why down vote :) in the question the 3rd image tag doesn't start properly,please look at this img class="thumbnail" id="idea" src="images/idea_thumbnail.jpg" alt="p" />

Comment: I've figured out. The problem is with the `img` before the one pointed out by the OP. It's the third. It has a missing `<` opening the tag.

Comment: @aria Please edit your answer and include the relevant information. The way it is now it's unclear. Nobody should rely on these comments to understand it.

Comment: yeah as pointed out, third image was missing < in the opening tag, will accept solution in a couple of minutes. thanks for the help